# Minimizing operations to reach a set of goal stack states

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, optimization, sorting

I'm trying to sort the elements of a set of "goal" stacks to minimize the number of pushes/pops to reach each state. The inputs and outputs can be some other structure rather than stacks, they just represent a target state of the stack. Each goal must be reached in the order given in the input.

For example, given this input of goal stacks:

```
Input
[[9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2],
 [9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [9, 7, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1],
 [9, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1],
 [9, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2]]
```

I want to produce an output like the following:

```
Output
[[9, 7, 2, 6, 4, 5],
 [9, 7, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1],  // 1 pop, 2 push
 [9, 7, 2, 5, 1, 5, 1],  // 4 pop, 4 push
 [9, 7, 2, 5, 1, 6],     // 2 pop, 1 push
 [9, 7, 2, 5, 6, 3]]     // 2 pop, 2 push
                         // 18 operations
```

I have tried sorting each list based on the common items in the next list, but without more look-ahead it produces a suboptimal solution. If I just sort based on the frequency distribution for all lists it also fails. Trying every permutation is the only approach that comes to mind.

Is there an efficient algorithm to correctly order the lists in this way?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow.  It looks like each row of your input is a stack that you're performing operations on, but I'm not sure.  Could you explain more, perhaps give an example of your stack operations.  Maybe walk through how you push and pop your inputs to get the outputs.  Like why aren't there any operations on the first row in your output?  It looks like it could be an interesting problem, but the more explanation, the better.